Error message regarding edit summary
As of this morning, I seem unable to put Edit summaries that I have used in the past. Specifically, I made two formatting edits, and attempted to write "Formatting" in the Edit summary box, only to get an error message that reads

Comment reserved for system use. Please use an appropriate comment.

(screenshot below)
I've received this error message both on Chrome running on an iPad (version 126.0.6478.108) and Chrome running on a Desktop on UNIX (Version 126.0.6478.126).
Screenshot follows.


On [meta.se]: "Comment reserved for system use" when trying to edit with an edit summary

@MartinSleziak Thanks. I searched "our" meta, but I don't usually think to look in Meta Stack Exchange.

Resolved on this MSE post

As noted in comments: this was a bug and the build that provoked it has been reverted.
